# Updating 2 columns from one excel workbook to other workbook

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have two worksheets Book A and Book B.

Book A has 3 columns

```
Elements (duck,
elephant,deer,monkey), Weight(20,70,18,25), Size(10,30,10,6)
```

respectively.

Book B has also same columns `Elements (elephant,deer), Weight (80,28) and size(40,20)` respectively.

I need to update weight and size of Animals column from Book B in Book A.
like.

deer has weight:28 and size:20 in Book B. then it should update deer's weight and size in Book A instead of weight:18 and size: 10.

I saw VLOOKUP function and some related questions but was unable to find it.
Please help me in this.
Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: So you just want to display the values from book B and not permanently overwrite the values in book A? If yes, VLOOKUP is what you need. Please google for that, there are many tutorials available.

Comment: no, I want to overwrite the values in BookA too.

Comment: Then you need a VBA macro such as the answer proposed below.

Comment: ya.. but I am getting error.. i dont know what is the reason.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

First open Book B
leave Book A closed
right click the sheet name and select view code
copy and paste this in
edit where stated
press the green play button or F5

***** Don't forget to save a backup copy of your files before running in case of any data corruption *****

```
Sub updateBook()

Dim loop1, loop2 As Long
Dim rows1, rows2 As Integer

Dim Path As String
Path = "Path to Book A"  'edit within the quotes the path to Book A file e.g C:\users\name\BookA.xlsm

Dim openWb As Workbook
Set openWb = Workbooks.Open(Path)

Dim openWs As Worksheet
Set openWs = openWb.Sheets("Sheet Name in Book A")   'edit within the quotes the sheet name of Book A

Dim currentWb As Workbook
Set currentWb = ThisWorkbook

Dim currentWs As Worksheet
Set currentWs = currentWb.Sheets("Sheet Name in Book B")  'edit within the quotes the sheet name of Book B

rows1 = currentWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count
rows2 = openWs.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For loop1 = 1 To rows1 Step 1
    For loop2 = 1 To rows2 Step 1
        If openWs.Cells(loop2, 1).Value = currentWs.Cells(loop1, 1).Value Then
        'check if names match between books
            openWs.Cells(loop2, 2).Value = currentWs.Cells(loop1, 2).Value
            'replaces the old value in 2nd column with new value from Book A
            openWs.Cells(loop2, 3).Value = currentWs.Cells(loop1, 3).Value
            'replaces the old value in 3rd column with new value from Book A
        End If
    Next loop2
Next loop1

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
openWb.Close (True)
'saves and closes book B

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But I am novice to this excel macro thing. But I am getting error in executing this. On debugging, I got after Workbook B gets opened. I am getting error. Could you please help me.

Comment: your data in columns with the headers which are outside the brackets right?

Comment: yes, it is outside bracket like this:
1st row: duck 20 10
2nd row: elephant 70 30.. and so on.

Comment: okay edited my answer for you for easier instructions. feel free to ask if anymore

Comment: Thanks. but now i am getting subscript out of range.

Comment: check the names properly it is case sensitive